# Should Observable call .onComplete() when Subscriber disposes?

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2, rxandroidble

I'm writing an Observable to handle connections to Android Services, modeled after `RxAndroidBle`'s `.establishConnection()`.

I know that `.establishConnection()` never calls `.onComplete()`; after it emits the connection it is either disposed by the Subscriber or ends with an error (typically if the connection is lost). But it seems reasonable that `.onComplete()` would be called when the connection is disposed. I haven't been able to find an official `RxJava` policy on this; it seems that some Observables do it and others don't. What is the correct behavior for an Observable that emits a single item and is then disposed?

Comment: Use `Single` instead.

Comment: Yes, I understand the use of `Single` and do use them in some of my code; however, when the source emits a "connection-type" event it is convenient to simply dispose the `Observable` to release the connection, the way `RxAndroidBle` does with Bluetooth LE connections. Singles don't provide this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct behavior for an Observable that emits a single item and is then disposed?

If I understood correctly this is a question about how the `Observable` should behave when disposed according to the official reactive policy. Actually both calling/not calling the `.onComplete()` when disposed is aligned to the [`Observable`'s contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) but the latter seems to be preferred (bolding mine):

> #### Observable Termination
>
> An Observable may begin issuing notifications to an observer immediately after the Observable receives a Subscribe notification from the observer.
>
> *When an observer issues an Unsubscribe notification to an Observable, the Observable will attempt to stop issuing notifications to the observer. It is not guaranteed, however, that the Observable will issue no notifications to the observer after an observer issues it an Unsubscribe notification.*
>
> When an Observable issues an OnError or OnComplete notification to its observers, this ends the subscription. Observers do not need to issue an Unsubscribe notification to end subscriptions that are ended by the Observable in this way.

Where notifications are:

To `Observer`:

- `OnNext`
- `OnCompleted`
- `OnError`
- `OnSubscribe` (optional)

To `ObservableSource`:

- `Subscribe`
- `Unsubscribe`
- `Request` (optional)

Comment: I've read the contract carefully and, as you note, there doesn't appear to be an unambiguous policy. It seems to me it should be both possible and desirable to have a clear ruling on this. Are there use cases that support both behaviors?

Comment: None that I am aware of. From my experience when an `Subscription` to an `Observable` is disposed the `Observer` "knows" that it will not get any further notifications